# When did lightsabers first appear in the Star Wars timeline?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, lightsaber

Where do we first see/read about a lightsaber in the Star Wars universe (EU and Legends count)?

I mean this from an in-universe chronological perspective, not publication/release order.

It’s a simple question, but I've searched some existing question and answers on here and a few other sites online (yes, including wookieepedia...) but have not found anything useful yet.

Comment: In the Star Wars: The Old Republic MMORPG, there's some story surrounding the creation of the first lightsaber in the story line quests of the Jedi Consular class (and perhaps the Jedi Knight class as well, I'm not sure). If I could find a write-up of it (or remembered more of it), I'd make it an answer. Hopefully, someone can provide more details for a well-written answer.

Comment: @Ellesedil - That would be cool! Unfortunately I never got around to playing that one...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In the Legends continuity, we first see a "Forcesaber" in the *[Star Wars: Dawn of the Jedi](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Dawn_of_the_Jedi)* series, which takes place about 26,000 years before the Battle of Yavin.

[image: Dawn of the Jedi: Force Storm]

We see our first true lightsaber in *Star Wars: The Old Republic*, appropriately titled the "[First Blade](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/First_Blade)." It was much older than the Republic (founded approximately 25,000 BBY), but its exact age is unknown.

[image: First Blade]

In regular canon, the first lightsaber we see is Qui-Gon Jin's (by a split-second) in *The Phantom Menace.*

[image: *Phantom Menace* lightsaber]

Comment: and this is why it was a good move to get rid of Legends overall and consolidate everything under the Lucasfilm Story Group.

Comment: the cover image notwithstanding - are there actually lightsabers in this series? The publisher's summary says: "Here begins the tale of the dawn of the Jedi, the Star Wars of 25,000 years ago—before lightsabers,..etc". I think these are called "Forcesabers" - which may be different technically (I've not read this series is why I ask)

Comment: It's even earlier than that. The Rakata had Forcesabers before the Tho Yor Arrival.

Comment: @RogueJedi I know. Star Wars: Dawn of the Jedi: The Prisoner of Bogan 4 shows them being around when the Tho Yor arrive.

Comment: @NKCampbell Updated.

Comment: Weren't there some more crude lightsabers before that, where the powerpack was not small enough to be contained in the handle, and it was in a backpack, connected to the lightsaber by cables? I no longer remember where did i read about it...

Comment: @vsz I added the first lightsaber-ish weapon and the first true lightsaber. I didn't add any proto-lightsabers from in-between since the the OP didn't ask for a complete history of lightsabers.

Comment: Forcesabers are not lightsabers. The lightsaber was first invented by the Jedi, and is of the wired belt pouch version. It is the Sith who brought forth almost all of the remaining technological advancements towards the modern lightsaber, such as the wireless closed feedback loop.

Comment: @thegreatjedi I never said it was a lightsaber. I merely recorded it as the first instance of a lightsaber-like weapon.

Comment: Interesting - how did they have cordless sabers 26,000 years before the films but were still using cables & battery packs 5,000 years before them?

Comment: @DCShannon Updated.

Comment: @Omegacron Retcons, I suppose.

Comment: The High Republic books and comics significantly predate *The Phantom Menace* in canon and extensively feature lightsabers

Answer (score 9):

**Legends**

According to [Wookieepedia](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Lightsaber/Legends) - 15,500 BBY if considering just the technical aspects if not total practicality

> By the time of the Duinuogwuin Contention around 15,500 BBY, Jedi
>   studies and researches with "frozen blaster" technology yielded
>   success; they developed a method to generate a focused beam of energy
>   that arced in a circumferential path back to its source, creating a
>   controlled energy circuit and leading to the first portable
>   high-energy blades. However, these preliminary lightsabers were highly
>   unstable and inefficiently guzzled energy from a belt-mounted power
>   supply; they could only be used for a brief duration before
>   overheating. As a consequence of these flaws, the first lightsabers
>   were little more than ceremonial objects, seldom worn, and much less
>   utilized.

Source: The New Essential Chronology (2005)

Comment: Hmm... I must've been on another page... Interesting excerpt. I feel like the movies would be much less interesting with these primitive weapons.

Answer (score 6):

As Legends canon is accepted, the date goes back a very, *very* long time ago (in a galaxy far, far away).

[Protosabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Protosaber), mentioned in Nathan's answer, were certainly an early (circa 15,500 BBY, as he stated) design of lightsaber -- but they were based on an even earlier design.
[image: Protosaber]

The Rakata Empire created the [Forcesabers](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Forcesaber), lightsabers essentially fueled by Dark Side Force energy.  Their non-Rakata Force users ("Force Hounds") would construct their own Forcesabers and attune special focus gems to their own Force signatures, like the Jedi in later millenia. The Rakata themselves used forcesabers in a force pike configuration.  However, the Forcesabers were created thousands of years before [The Tho Yor Arrival](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Tho_Yor_Arrival) (circa 36,453 BBY), which itself marked the beginning of the proliferation of Force usage.

[image: Forcesaber]

The Jed'aii descendents of those taught in the Tho Yor pyramid ships would attempt to use Forcesabers only at great risk -- the Dark Side influence of the sabers made them highly corruptive.

This, in turn, spurred the development of the aforementioned Protosabers which, being powered by a power pack rather than Dark Side Force energy, did not corrupt the user.

Answer (score 3):

Considering only EU novels and stories, if you look at the [book timeline](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Timeline_of_Legends_books) page, the first novel has no lightsabers, but the second one, [Star Wars: Lost Tribe of the Sith: The Collected Stories](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Lost_Tribe_of_the_Sith:_The_Collected_Stories), says on page 3 "The half smirk was a memento from a Jedi Lightsaber swipe years earlier...". so this book, which is just a collection of short stories, is the first chronological reference to lightsabers. The stories in this collection take place between 5000 BBY and 2975 BBY.

The next reference after these short stories is in the novel [The Old Republic: Revan](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Old_Republic:_Revan).

As for canon material, Phantom Menace is the first instance at the year of 32 BBY.

Answer (score 1):

See other responses for Legends canon.
For Abrams's canon, this may be explained in the upcoming movies

> since Luke was in search of the first Jedi Temple.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Abram's canon doesn't have an answer to this yet... or for lots of other things, for that matter.

Answer (score 1):

### Canon: at least as early as c. 25,020 BBY

In the Canon reference book [*Star Wars: Timelines*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Timelines), the timeline showing the early history of the Jedi Order has an entry for when the droid [Professor Huyang](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Huyang) started teaching young Jedi how to build lightsabers:

> ##### ESTIMATED
>
> **c.25,020 BBY: Professor Huyang powered up**
>
> The architect droid Professor Huyang begins training Jedi younglings in the delicate art of lightsaber construction.
>
> <sub>(*Star Wars: Timelines*, page 11)</sub>

This is apparently in reference to one of his lines from the episode [*A Test of Strength*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/A_Test_of_Strength) from *The Clone Wars*:

> HUYANG: If I may, sir—I have instructed younglings for over a thousand generations, and these are among the best I have ever seen.
>
> <sub>(*The Clone Wars* S5E7: *A Test of Strength*)</sub>